# Multi level Dropdown menu bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a multi level dropdown menu, but not getting very far, what I'd like is to have in the dropdown is:

```
1.one menu option
  - sub-menu option
  - sub-menu option
  - sub-menu option
2.another menu
  - sub-menu option
```

etc

up to 4 options in the main menu with sub menus for each menu item.

here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="dropdown">
           <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories
           <span class="caret"></span></button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Sports</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">... <span class="caret"></span></a>

             <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Pop Culture</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">... <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Tazos</a></li> 
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

any help greatly appreciated....

Comment: https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See online working example:
https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

another link:https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD

**Edit the code according to your requirements**

Comment: That looks like it might work. Will have a look in a minute and mark this as answer if it works...cheers!

Comment: You know what? I figured out what I was doing wrong! Such a rollercoaster! I got it to do what I wanted using basically the code you shared, so you get the correct answer! Well done! Thanks again!